# Database design for statistics of views/likes/downloads?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, usage-statistics

So i am trying to work out a database design to keep track of views, likes and downloads. Now the amount of entries to keep track of is expected to be 1m or more, so normally i would just track each entry daily, but with 1m i am having concerns about performance and maybe even size on harddisk.

Customers wish is being able to show top statistics in ranges like last week, last month, last year. So i am not sure if should split the data up by adding up numbers from days to weeks or months and delete everything else that isn't relevant any more or just keep it a bit more flexible by tracking all of it, being able to query needed statistics freely.

Database: MySQL

I have to take save the counters once a day.

Comment: Have you decided which database you are storing it in? Do these figures need to be completely up to date (i.e. in the last second). There are many solutions. For example you could run a job everyday that generates those summaries into a simple table. What time period of data does 1 million records cover? Lastly... wherever you're getting this data from might already have a tool that does this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Well it data should be collected once a day, database is mysql. I would have to keep track of a total all time, which isn't an issue and up to 1 year, which would result in 365m+ entries if i would get the count once a day.

So i basically lack the experience on how this would affect performance as my previous projects got me to a couple 10k per table at most.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep track of it daily and then by the end of the week you delete the daily stats and you do so for the weekly data by the second week and do on for the months and year if you want to keep your last stats. You can create a job to make this job. I hope this may help you.

Comment: I agree. If you don't have any use for individual historic entries, don't keep them (although you might want to store them in some kind of "big data" store for later analysis)

Answer (score 0):

Due the operation only appending the data, store it on time series format.

Whenever you receive the clicks/views data goes in, count it and put the result as smallest dimension as we can. If we can summarizing it hourly, it's best choice ~ good for performance. Whenever we need to know data from higher dimension, just sum it up. Don't counting it (the statistic) on demand, for example : Scanning 10 millions of rows just for counting 1 day data, this is heavy operation.

With this approach you will save two thing :

1. Storage, you can backup older data that more than x times ( example more than 3 months), so the db size keep compact
2. Performance